# Coordinates heat map results are not the same as the shapefile

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I have done with a heat map shapefiles as shown below. But the results of heat map coordinates are not the same as the coordinates of shapefiles. Is there a procedure that is wrong?

[image: shapefile and heat map with coordinate, qgis ver.2.8.1]

Comment: Thanks Vince, I used qgis ver.2.8.1.The step that I have taken :  1. Raster>> Heat Map, Radius= 600, >> OK.2.Layer Properties > style, > Singleband Ps.> classfy, > OK . Coordinate shapefile is 119.47882,-5.09288,with  CRS wgs 84. And coordinate heatmap is 170,-441 with  CRS wgs 84 too.

Comment: I can fix my problem with :Until it get fixed You can do as follows with one more step:

Calculate heatmap as normal
Create new raster with Raster > Projections > Warp(Reproject) - leave the original projection
Magic - the new raster is exactly where it belongs :)
I got this answer from @Joseph who gave helpful comment in the duplicate thread: QGIS 2.8 Raster Layers Moved and encouraged me to post it here.